# c++ bank account array, looping through

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think I need to perform a multidimensional array or vector within it will define account and balance. Such as I defined {acctnum=44421, balance=0} by default the balance would be 0, and then I want to define another account {acctnum=55531, balance=""}. With each of these I need to take the first account with deposit and perform a withdrawal 10 then deposit 6. Then go to second deposit 3 and then deposit 5. Then display the intial deposit, then after withdrawal and after second deposit and what the account is after these actions.

**header**

```
#ifndef account_h_
#define account_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <account>

using std::account;

class account
{
public:
    account();
    account(const std::string acctnum);
    ~account();
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    const std:string get_acctnum() const{
        return m_acctnum;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //deposit
    void deposit(float amt){
        m_balance += amt;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //withdraw
    void withdraw(float amt){
        m_balance -= amt;
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //current balance
    const double get_balance() const{
        return m_balance;
    })
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //display string
    const std::string asString() const;     

private:
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //account number
    int m_acctnum;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //balance
    double m_balance;
    //----------------------------------------------------
    //after deposit or withdrawal
    void inc(const double d) {
        m_reading += d;
    }
};

#endif
```

**program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "account.h"
using namespace std;



//----------------------------------------------------
//bank account default balance
account::account(){
    m_balance = 0;
    m_acctnum = "???";
}
account::account(const std::string acctnum){
    m_balance = 0;
    m_acctnum = acctnum;
}
account::~account(){    
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//deposit
void account::deposit(double amount){
    balance = balance + amount;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//withdraw
void account::withdraw(double amount){
    if(amount < balance ){
        std::cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance." 
        << amount << endl;
    }
    else if(amount < 0){
        std::cout <<"The withdrawel you've enter is defined as negative." 
        << amount << endl;
    }
    else{
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//get balance
double account::get_balance() const{
    return balance;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//display
const std::string account::asstring() const{
    ostringstream oss;

    oss << "Account Num: " << m_acctnum <<
           " Balance: " << m_balance;
    return oss.str();
}
```

**Test Program** This is where I am having trouble in creating the program to do this. I think I need an array, maybe multidimensional array and access to the balance so I can perform deposits and withdrawals on??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "account.h"



void main(){
    account::account[][2] = {
        {44421, 20},
        {55531, }
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 2 ; ++col)
        {
            account::deposit[col]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, maybe you could post a legible question, instead. It's completely unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited it* @SamVarshavchik

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with your code.

```
//account number
int m_acctnum;
```

Your class member is an `int`.

```
const std:string get_acctnum() const{
    return m_acctnum;
}

account::account(const std::string acctnum){
    m_balance = 0;
    m_acctnum = acctnum;
}
```

But your methods think it's a `std::string`. You cannot assign a `std::string` to an `int`. Similarly, you cannot convert an `int` directly to a `std::string`.

I'm sure your compiler reported all of these as errors. Did you understand your compiler's error messages? Here's a simple question, do you think that the following piece of code is valid:

```
int n="the rain in spain falls mainly in the plane";
```

Of course not, yet this is what you're trying to do, and, of course, the compiler can't be happy about it.

```
account::account[][2] = {
    {44421, 20},
    {55531, }
};
```

It's not clear what this is supposed to be, either. Each instance of an class is instantiated by either explicitly invoking the class's constructor, or using the class's default constructors; and then assigning it to a variable. Class instances are not instantiated by manually initializing private class members.

Your `account` class has a default constructor, and a constructor that takes one parameter. Your class does not have any constructors that take two parameters, so this is not a valid initialization.

Additionally, a class is constructed by giving the class's name, and the name of the class instance, and not by explicitly invoking the class's constructor.

```
        account::deposit[col]
```

account::deposit() is a class method. It is not a static class function that can be invoked like that. Additionally, parameters to either a class method, or a static class functions are passed using parenthesis, not brackets.

Additionally, the deposit() method takes a parameter that's described as a "balance". It is not a "column number" type of a parameter.